# I started getting to know pandas via a youtube-tutorial. After comleting the tutorial i encountered the following problem:

Tags: python, pandas

I was working with the exact same csv-file the tutorial provided. While doing the tutorial i did not encounter the error. when trying to build onto my knowledge i acquired during the tutorial i got the following error, althought i did not change the data in the file, or anything with the code, if you can even call it code. Searched the internet for similar errors, but did not find anything.

The code:

```
> import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("pokemon_data.csv")
print(df.columns)
print(df.columns["Speed"])
```

the error:

```
> File "c:/Users/pgw19/Documents/python/scripts_own/kampagnentool.py", line 5, in <module>      
    print(df.columns["Speed"])
  File "C:\Users\pgw19\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4297, in __getitem__
    return getitem(key)
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

My question: how do i solve the error and make sure it does not happen again?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: `print(df["Speed"])`?

Comment: Instead of ```df.columns["Speed"]``` you should use ```df["Speed"]```

Comment: "Speed" refers to the name of the column i want to print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.columns` will return an Index like this. You can think of it as a list of the names of the columns:

`Index(['Size', 'Speed', 'RPM'], dtype='object')`

You *could* extract an element from the Index, but it would just return a string:

`df.columns[1]` would return `Speed`.

Probably, what you want is to actually get a column from the dataframe! You could do this with

`df['Speed']` or `df.Speed` - not by going through the `df.columns` attribute.